# Segfault: don't know where to start

Tags: c, boot, segmentation-fault

I'm trying to compile [this program](http://pastebin.com/KgmFT2MD) under Windows
(it's a program which turns bootable code in floppies. I got the source from here: http://www.acm.uiuc.edu/sigops/roll_your_own/1.bootstrap.html).

First I got the problem that it didn't read the INI file. That is solved now. Now I get a segfault on the following rule:

```
while(data < end)
```

I added output to the app, so it should be clear where the executing stops: no "."'s are printed out. I'm on Win64, with the Cygwin toolchain.

Thanks!

Yvan

Comment: I thought I was the last person on Earth using floppies :D :D ( http://superuser.com/questions/135661/are-floppy-disks-still-used-in-the-software-world )

Comment: Don't link to external pages. Code should be in the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A mistake is:

```
size = (int *)lSize;
```

Better:

```
*size = lSize;
```

and the function as:

```
void *loadfile(char *file, long *size)
...
```

and in calling context eg:

```
long size=0;
char *buffer = loadfile("blah.txt",&size);
if( buffer )
{
  printf("\nstrlen = %lu, fsize = &ld", strlen(buffer), size );
}
```